# Django check if superuser in class-based view

Tags: python, django

I am converting my project from function-based view to class-based view. In a view function, I can check if a user is a superuser using `request.user.is_superuser()` function. I can check if a user is logged in by inheriting `LoginRequiredMixin` in a `View` class, I want to know if there is any similar way that can be used for checking if the user is a superuser in a `View` class. I want a Django app only accessible by the superusers of the site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create your own :

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin

class SuperUserRequiredMixin(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin):

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_superuser
```

and then instead of using **LoginRequiredMixin** in your **ClassBasedView** you use your **SuperUserRequiredMixin**

Now your view will only allow logged-in superuser.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Where should I place the custom class for best practice?

Comment: honestly i don't know what would be the "best practice", but i would put it in a mixins.py or permissions.py file(a separated file generally ) and import when needed

Answer (score -1):

He is an example use case of what you are trying to accomplish. You need `self.request.user.is_superuser`.

```
class ExampleClassView(LoginRequiredMixin,TemplateView):
    template_name = "core/index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["is_super"] = self.request.user.is_superuser
        return context
```